# How can I stop a running R command in linux other than with Ctrl + C?

Tags: linux, r, command

I'm running R in interactive mode under Linux and mistakenly typed in a command that takes forever to run. I usually stop it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. But it doesn't work all the time. When it doesn't work, is there another way?

I don't want to kill the R session to start over either.

Answer (score 39):

I have had the problem you mention. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will work when R is able to realize "Oh, this guy/gal wants me to stop running that particular command." However, often R cannot do that. So you have to run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> (note that it's a backslash, not a forward slash). This tells Linux "Hey, R is not listening to me, can you stop running R?".

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> first, because if it works you will still have your R session. If it doesn't work, and you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> you will lose your R session, but at least it stops the process.

If that doesn't work either, then I would suggest a `killall R` or a `kill -9 [PID]` where you find the PID by running `pus aux`.

Comment: When Ctrl+C doesn't work, it's usually because you have called a function that calls compiled code that doesn't check for user interrupt.  These are usually in user-supplied packages, not base/recommended R packages.

Comment: Thanks for the response, although I was looking for a solution that can keep the R session alive.

Comment: @danioyuan, from what I gather from Joshua's comment, that may not be possible with some of the functions you are calling - they are free to ignore user interrupts.

Answer (score 10):

Try to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, pause R with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, and then unpause R with `fg` (#job).

I tried the solutions given in previous answers with sending some signals to R with kill, but neither worked. Then I tried the sequence above (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, and `fg 1`) and it worked. I could continue the R session.

I'm not sure whether it was one of the signals or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> that stopped R, but I guess <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> was essential here.

Answer (score 8):

You can also try

```
kill -USR1 [pid]
```

This will interrupt some R calls and sometimes give you the option to save and quit rather killing the process altogether.

Comment: Unless you tell users what `[PID]` might stand for (i.e. how to find out about it, your answer is useless

Comment: reference https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Signals.html

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is not working. Somehow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> will stop the process.

But there is a function in R programming to quit. You can try ***q()*** on REPL. It worked for me.

```
q()
```

Comment: What is "RPEL"? Do you mean [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop)?